# Reverse of a number using recursion with return and without return

Tags: c++, recursion

Why does the following code prints 0 in the `main` function without the return statement on the recursive function call:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int num, int rev = 0)
{
    if(num == 0)
        return rev;
    reverse(num / 10, rev * 10 + (num % 10));
}
int main()
{
    cout << reverse(123);
    return 0;
}
```

But with return statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int num, int rev = 0)
{
    if(num == 0)
        return rev;
    return reverse(num / 10, rev * 10 + (num % 10));
}
int main()
{
    cout << reverse(123);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints 321. I used GDB and value of rev is 321 in both the cases just before returning back to main function then why this difference?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. If you declare function to return `int`,  then it must return an `int` in all branches of execution. Turn on your compiler warning to help catch such issues.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. Consider what happens if `num != 0` and `reverse` calls some other function. What would it return in your cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's visualize execution of this code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int num, int rev = 0)
{
    if(num == 0)
        return rev;
    reverse(num / 10, rev * 10 + (num % 10));
}
int main()
{
    cout << reverse(123);
    return 0;
}
```

```
reverse(123, 0) ⟶ reverse(12, 3) ⟶ reverse(1, 32) ⟶ reverse(0, 321)
```

Now `reverse(0, 321)` returns `rev` (`321`) to its caller function (`reverse(1, 32)`) because `num == 0`.

Now our control is in `reverse(1, 32)`, where value of `num` is `1` which is `!= 0` and since `num != 0`, there is no return statement to execute.
Hence no value returned from `reverse(1, 32)`, then again no value return from `reverse(12, 3)` and at last no value returned from `reverse(123, 0)`.

In this case, a value `0` or a garbage value is expected to be returned. In your case it returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

At a low level, a program has access to a small number of named memory locations, known as registers. In assembly, there is a special register called %rax that is used to store the return value of a function. So, if you wanted to store the result of a function called `foo(x)` in a variable `a`, you would do something like
`a = foo(x)`.

As for the reason why `rev` is 321 right before the return to the main function, it is possible that the correct return value is indeed stored in `%rax`, but because you do not explicitly return it, the program overwrites `%rax` with the value 0 when you return to the main function. If you'd like to learn more about this, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) might have some useful information for you.

However, as another answer has mentioned, the fact that `rev` is 321 before returning to `main` is undefined behavior, and should not be considered a property of the language.